# checkbox onclicklistener not working in list row android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, listactivity, onclicklistener

my list row contains a check box with some other views also. when i check or uncheck the checkbox, its associated action listener is not fired. Following is the code snippet for getView(). Please have a look and provide me with the solution.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            Log.i("adapter", "ADAPTER");
        }

        checkTax = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_tax);
        checkTax.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener () {      
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)          {
                        Log.i("on click", "ON CLICK");
                if (isChecked) {
                    tvSelectTaxAccount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    spinnerTaxAcc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tvTaxAmt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editTaxAmt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tvAmtAfterTax.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    amtAfterTax.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tvAmt.setText("amount before tax");
                    Log.i("checked", "CHECKED");
                }
                else
                {
                    tvSelectTaxAccount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    spinnerTaxAcc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tvTaxAmt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    editTaxAmt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tvAmtAfterTax.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    amtAfterTax.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tvAmt.setText("AMOUNT");
                    Log.i("unchecked", "UNCHECKED");
                }
            }

        });

        tvSelectTaxAccount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_select_tax_account);
        spinnerTaxAcc = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_tax_acc);
        spinnerTaxAcc.setOnItemSelectedListener(selectSpinnerTaxAcc);

        tvTaxAmt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_tax_amt);
        editTaxAmt = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_tax_amt);
        tvAmt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_amt);
        tvAmtAfterTax = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_amt_after_tax);
        amtAfterTax = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amt_after_tax);

    spinnerTaxAcc.setOnItemSelectedListener(selectSpinnerTaxAcc);

        tvSelectTaxAccount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spinnerTaxAcc.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        tvTaxAmt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editTaxAmt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvAmtAfterTax.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        amtAfterTax.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uncomment this line `//checkTax.setOnClickListener(tax);` and try using a onclicklistener or try using

```
checkTax.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

   if(isChecked)
   {
    checkTax.setText("Check Box is checked");
   }
   else
   {
    checkTax.setText("not checked");
   }

});
```

i think even setOnCheckedChangeListener will be fired on clicking a checkbox

Comment: But onClickListener gets fired if i don't use Activity instead of a ListActivity.

Comment: ok but even onclicklistener should work fine. Donno why it didnt. Anywayz good to hear that it works fine. Happy coding

Comment: just changed onClickListener to setOncheckedChangeListener(). and the code remains same as in the snippet above.i have written Log.i statements inside if and else.Its showing Log statements but .setVisibility statements are not getting executed

Comment: try using ischecked instead of the entire code.Check the edited one

Comment: yes i have done this only and have written spinnerTaxAcc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); inside if block. When i check the check box, the spinner is not being visible.

Comment: once check if the list item is visible totally by making it visible in the xml layout. (i mean to say this because the views in each item sometimes may not be visible )

Comment: it was visible initially. I set its visibility to Gone. I need to make it visible again when i check the CheckBox.

Comment: could you edit the question to the latest improvement so that we can check what's actually happening

Comment: once could you check the value of isChecked by printing it in the logcat. I think its always false or something strange is happening over there

Comment: Log.i statements r printed correctly in the logcat.That means it is going correctly in if and else part,but .Visibility statments are not working

Comment: do you mean you are getting checked  and unchecked when checkbox is clicked?

Comment: i doubt...  if you have all the views (that you are not getting visible even after checked the checkbox) are in a seperate layout check that the particular layout is not invisible